# ID3 tags are read incorrectly

Tags: mp3, id3, cdex

Recently, I re-ripped quite a few of my CDs at a higher bitrate using CDex. However, I wasn't aware that the default setting of ID3v2.4 would cause problems with Windows Media Player (Win7x64) as well as my portable MP3 player.

The first thing I did was search this site, and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/143297/check-id3-tag-integrity-from-mp3-almost-a-debug-is-it-possible) question with a lot of good advice. I downloaded Mp3tag, and found its interface to be fairly intuitive and easy to use. It chugged along, updating several thousand MP3s from ID3v2.4 to ID3v2.3. However, WMP and my MP3 player still don't "get it". WMP3 sees the song title in the synch list, but refuses to acknowledge the artist or album in most cases. The MP3 player has the same problem, so I think this is a problem with the files themselves.

For example, if I synch up two Alice in Chains songs, I see the following in WMP:

```
Rooster (Live) 6:54
Alice in Chains - Main In The Box 4:47
```

When I view the ID3 tags in WMP, Explorer, Mp3tag, and Foobar, they are correct. I exported the tag contents to CSV from Mp3tag and these are the results:

```
Title;Artist;Album;Track;Year;Length;Size;Last Modified;Path;Filename;
Man In The Box;Alice in Chains;Nothing Safe (Best Of The Box);;;287;7.47 MB;7/13/2011;C:\Music\Alice In Chains\Nothing Safe (Best Of The Box)\;Alice in Chains - Man In The Box.mp3;
Rooster (Live);Alice in Chains;Nothing Safe (Best Of The Box);;;414;9.98 MB;7/13/2011;C:\Music\Alice In Chains\Nothing Safe (Best Of The Box)\;Alice in Chains - Rooster (Live).mp3;
build on 7/13/2011 with Mp3tag v2.49 - the universal Tag editor - http://www.mp3tag.de/en/
```

Everything appears to be correct: Mp3tag reports there are ID3v1 and ID2v2.3 tags. Removing the version 1 tags in Mp3tag (several questions said to do this, since nobody uses them anymore) causes both songs to exhibit the aberrant behavior. This is consistent: it has happened with several albums now that I have been experimenting with.

I also tried TagScanner, but have not been able to figure it out. I am not sure that it can do anything Mp3tag cannot do anyway.

One last note: if I right click a song in the synch list and select properties, I see the title, artist and album listed correctly in WMP7. Yet it will not display correctly in the synch list, and subsequently does not show up correctly in my MP3 player.

Any ideas on how to get WMP7 to see the artist and album data in the synch list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are jumping the gun a bit with the new version tags. Just because something is new and has been updated does not mean that it has been **adopted** and put in to actual use. Revert the tags to a readable format.

Comment: There is plenty of documented evidence that WMP cannot handle ID3v2.4, such as http://superuser.com/questions/286483/why-do-most-of-my-mp3s-show-up-as-unknown-artist-album-in-the-zune-software as well as wikipedia and plenty of google links.